# setCurrentItem call on ViewPager causes app to crash with outofmemory error

Tags: android, image, android-fragments

I am trying to create an app that has a bunch of low res images (each image around 50 - 70 KB). One could swipe through the image library, or based on certain buttons, go to specific image in the library. I used the ViewPager using the FragmentStatePagerAdapter (FSPA) as I understand that this is the most memory optimal way for swiping through images. I am expecting that this approach ensures that only 3 images/fragments are alive at any given point in time, hence there shouldn't be a memory issue as such. This approach works fine on most emulators. However, when I try with Nexus One emulator (I am using Android Studio), I see an issue. The swiping part works fine, but if I use a button to go to a specific page (using viewPager.SetCurrentItem() method), the app crashes with outofmemory error. What do I need to do to get this working (going to a particular image on click of a button)?

I have a main activity page, and two fragment pages. Here is the code:

Main activity page:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.example.tryslider.tryslider.MainActivity">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

fragment pager (with the ViewPager and button):

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#5b9bd5"
    android:padding="4dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/goButtonLabel"
            android:id="@id/goButton"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </LinearLayout>
```

fragment that contains the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/first" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my main activity code (notice the number in SetCurrentItem - I just move to an arbitrary image in the stack, say 5th image in this case (out of a total of 10 images):

```
package com.example.tryslider.tryslider;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final int ITEMS = 10;
    MyAdapter viewAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private Button goButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        viewAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewAdapter);

        goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);

        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(5, false);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ImageFragment.init(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
            super.destroyItem(collection, position, o);
            View view = (View)o;
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
            view = null;
        }

    }

}
```

And the image fragment code:

```
package com.example.tryslider.tryslider;

/**
 * Created by rahul on 8/3/14.
 */

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    private int index;
    private int[] mImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.first,
            R.drawable.second,
            R.drawable.third,
            R.drawable.fourth,
            R.drawable.fifth,
            R.drawable.sixth,
            R.drawable.seventh,
            R.drawable.eighth,
            R.drawable.ninth,
            R.drawable.tenth
    };
    static ImageFragment init(int val) {
        ImageFragment myFrag = new ImageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", val);
        myFrag.setArguments(args);
        return myFrag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        index = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container,
                false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[index]);

        return layoutView;
    }
}
```

I tried going through many suggestions on SO and otherwise, but am struggling with this at the moment. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
        super.destroyItem(collection, position, o);
        View view = (View)o;
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
        view = null;
    }
```

This section is not needed. The FragmentStatePager will handle destroying and recreating views.